# Open terminal, run SSH then switch user

Tags: ssh

I manage to SSH to a remote host after opening the GNOME terminal by doing the following:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "ssh -i ~/.ssh/virtual_machines remote@remotehost; exec bash;"
```

However, once I have SSH into the remote host, I want to switch user by doing a `sudo su test`. I have already added the command in the visudo:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:/bin/su test
```

Once I have switched to test, the test user will start a program and remain on that program.

Modifying the .bashrc file is not an option as I also SSH as this user and do not want the program to start automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to start a `gnome-terminal` window/tab inside which is started a login shell session running as `test` on `remotehost`, that would be:

```
gnome-terminal -- ssh -i ~/.ssh/virtual_machines -t remote@remotehost 'exec sudo -iu test'
```

Using `su` in combination with `sudo` sounds a bit silly to me. `sudo` can do what `su` can do and gives you much more flexibility as to defining what is allowed by whom.

```
%wheel  ALL=(test) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Would allow any user in the `wheel` group to run any command as the `test` user without password prompt, including `sudo -i -u test` to start a login session as `test`.

Comment: I got to work by setting ```visudo``` as: ```%wheel  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/su test *``` and running the shell as follows: ```gnome-terminal -- ssh -i ~/.ssh/virtual_machines -t remote@remotehost 'sudo su test -c "screen -D -R screen-session vim"'```

Answer (score 0):

The `exec bash` behind the ssh command does not do anything. The semicolon separates the commands in your initial shell, not in your ssh session. To start a command in your ssh session just append the command to execute.

Following this, what about switch to the user test

- before ssh to the remotehost

  ```
  sudo su test
  ssh remotehost programname
  ```

  for this to work, you may want to create a file `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remotehost containing the public key of the user test. Then you will not need a password to login.
- or while doing ssh to the remote host?

  ```
  ssh test@remotehost programname
  ```

  for this to work, you may want to create a file `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remotehost containing *your* public key. Then you will not need a password to login.
- or you could do

  ```
  ssh -t remotehost "sudo su test -c programname"
  ```

Comment: I can't SSH directly into user test because the folder permission is 770. The current SSH configuration will not let be SSH unless the folder is set to 700. When I start the terminal with the following command ```gnome-terminal -- bash -c "ssh  -i ~/.ssh/virtual_machines -t remote@remotehost \'sudo su test -c vim\';"```, it opens and closes immediately.

Comment: Did you try `ssh -t remote@remotehost` - note the option `-t`, this allocates a pseudo-terminal, cf. the man page. With multiple -t you may force to allocate a tty.